# How to setup a local authentication in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have connected firebase login to my test app and want to use local authentication there.
I have seen many examples that are based on local_auth package but they only show how to authenticate locally, but I wanted to use email and password after authenticating .

for more clrity, I read a post from medium where it says:

**  When a user after first sign-in/signup decides to activate authentication using the above methods, he/she practically says save my login credentials in a local host where nobody without a registered fingerprint and face ID can access. So when the users come into login and decide to use this method it basically fetches the login credentials from where it was locally stored. **

But how can I implement this in flutter?

Comment: save the login credentials after first signin with `flutter_secure_storage` package and then retrieve them only if the local authentication was successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Store Your Credentials Like this Example . Kindly Have a Look

---

```
  dependencies:
          flutter_secure_storage: ^5.0.2
```

---

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: ItemsWidget()));
}

class ItemsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ItemsWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ItemsWidgetState createState() => _ItemsWidgetState();
}

enum _Actions { deleteAll }
enum _ItemActions { delete, edit, containsKey }

class _ItemsWidgetState extends State<ItemsWidget> {
  final _storage = const FlutterSecureStorage();
  final _accountNameController =
      TextEditingController(text: 'flutter_secure_storage_service');

  List<_SecItem> _items = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _accountNameController.addListener(() => _readAll());
    _readAll();
  }

  Future<void> _readAll() async {
    final all = await _storage.readAll(
        iOptions: _getIOSOptions(), aOptions: _getAndroidOptions());
    setState(() {
      _items = all.entries
          .map((entry) => _SecItem(entry.key, entry.value))
          .toList(growable: false);
    });
  }

  void _deleteAll() async {
    await _storage.deleteAll(
        iOptions: _getIOSOptions(), aOptions: _getAndroidOptions());
    _readAll();
  }

  void _addNewItem() async {
    final String key = _randomValue();
    final String value = _randomValue();

    await _storage.write(
        key: key,
        value: value,
        iOptions: _getIOSOptions(),
        aOptions: _getAndroidOptions());
    _readAll();
  }

  IOSOptions _getIOSOptions() => IOSOptions(
        accountName: _getAccountName(),
      );

  AndroidOptions _getAndroidOptions() => const AndroidOptions(
        encryptedSharedPreferences: true,
      );

  String? _getAccountName() =>
      _accountNameController.text.isEmpty ? null : _accountNameController.text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                key: const Key('add_random'),
                onPressed: _addNewItem,
                icon: const Icon(Icons.add)),
            PopupMenuButton<_Actions>(
                key: const Key('popup_menu'),
                onSelected: (action) {
                  switch (action) {
                    case _Actions.deleteAll:
                      _deleteAll();
                      break;
                  }
                },
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
                    <PopupMenuEntry<_Actions>>[
                      const PopupMenuItem(
                        key: Key('delete_all'),
                        value: _Actions.deleteAll,
                        child: Text('Delete all'),
                      ),
                    ])
          ],
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            if (!kIsWeb && Platform.isIOS)
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: _accountNameController,
                  decoration:
                      const InputDecoration(labelText: 'kSecAttrService'),
                ),
              ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _items.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => ListTile(
                  trailing: PopupMenuButton(
                      key: Key('popup_row_$index'),
                      onSelected: (_ItemActions action) =>
                          _performAction(action, _items[index], context),
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
                          <PopupMenuEntry<_ItemActions>>[
                            PopupMenuItem(
                              value: _ItemActions.delete,
                              child: Text(
                                'Delete',
                                key: Key('delete_row_$index'),
                              ),
                            ),
                            PopupMenuItem(
                              value: _ItemActions.edit,
                              child: Text(
                                'Edit',
                                key: Key('edit_row_$index'),
                              ),
                            ),
                            PopupMenuItem(
                              value: _ItemActions.containsKey,
                              child: Text(
                                'Contains Key',
                                key: Key('contains_row_$index'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ]),
                  title: Text(
                    _items[index].value,
                    key: Key('title_row_$index'),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    _items[index].key,
                    key: Key('subtitle_row_$index'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );

  Future<void> _performAction(
      _ItemActions action, _SecItem item, BuildContext context) async {
    switch (action) {
      case _ItemActions.delete:
        await _storage.delete(
            key: item.key,
            iOptions: _getIOSOptions(),
            aOptions: _getAndroidOptions());
        _readAll();

        break;
      case _ItemActions.edit:
        final result = await showDialog<String>(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => _EditItemWidget(item.value));
        if (result != null) {
          await _storage.write(
              key: item.key,
              value: result,
              iOptions: _getIOSOptions(),
              aOptions: _getAndroidOptions());
          _readAll();
        }
        break;
      case _ItemActions.containsKey:
        final result = await _storage.containsKey(key: item.key);
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text('Contains Key: $result'),
          // backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 4),
        ));
        break;
    }
  }

  String _randomValue() {
    final rand = Random();
    final codeUnits = List.generate(20, (index) {
      return rand.nextInt(26) + 65;
    });

    return String.fromCharCodes(codeUnits);
  }
}

class _EditItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  _EditItemWidget(String text)
      : _controller = TextEditingController(text: text);

  final TextEditingController _controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: const Text('Edit item'),
      content: TextField(
        key: const Key('title_field'),
        controller: _controller,
        autofocus: true,
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        TextButton(
            key: const Key('cancel'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            child: const Text('Cancel')),
        TextButton(
            key: const Key('save'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(_controller.text),
            child: const Text('Save')),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _SecItem {
  _SecItem(this.key, this.value);

  final String key;
  final String value;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a simple example for saving and retrieving user credentials in/from secure storage. the example above contains everything and somehow tough.